# PC Boot status text has the first character missing on each output line to monitor

Tags: desktop-computer

t kinda looks  
 
ike this as each  
ine is output  
o the monitor.  
BC could be ABC or 1BC or?  
ho knows?  
ot me.

Thanks, Bob

Comment: What do you mean by PC Boot status text? Is the background black by any chance (The monitor sometimes makes mistakes auto aligning on black backgrounds (weird!))?...

Comment: When it boots up, have you tried doing the monitors 'auto scale' option? Some monitors have an option in their menu's that say something to the effect of 'auto size' or 'auto scale' that will try and auto adjust the field of view of the monitor so you can see everything .. sometimes the monitor doesn't adjust itself properly when switching between different resolutions (as happens when booting/rebooting) and the screen can sometimes be offset and appear to be missing text .. ?